# Laravel cast route parameter to Integer

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I really like the idea of *Route Model Binding*.

Is there a similar way to cast parameters (which are Strings) to Intergers?

The reason is that I often have the parameters `year` and `month`, but I would like to have it as an Integer, because the database seems to handle String and Integers in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use `Route Binding` similar to what I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146836/load-objects-with-parameters-from-laravel-ioc-container/33148257#33148257). It's unfortunate that it exists but is not documented in the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 4):

Update using PHP7, if anyone else comes looking:

```
public function view(int $id)
{
  echo gettype($id);
  // Outputs "integer"
}
```